# Calculating the rate of return (ROR) when buying and selling bonds that carry cupons?

Tags: bonds

Suppose I have bought a bond in some price - X, for 10 years.
Now I decide to sell it 2 years after the purchase for some price - Y.
I would like to calculate the ROR I got from this bond.

My real question is if I should annualize the cOupons I got while holding the bond?

I would like to get the 'r' from:

x*(1+r)=2c+y

OR

x*(1+r)=c+y + c*(R_of_market)

OR

I'm horribly mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, assume that the purchase and sale both take place on an annual coupon date, *after* that day's coupon is cashed.

Arbitrarily, (won't change the answer) take the date of sale as the reference date, for comparing different amounts.  Let r be the annual rate of return, and C is the value of the annual coupon.

1. As of that date, the value of all expenditures (the purchase) is X * (1 + r)^2
2. As of that date, the value of the coupons is C + C * (1 + r)
3. As of that date, the value of the sale is Y

Set 1) + 2) = 3) and solve for r

For this or more complicated situations, the Excel function XIRR accepts a schedule of irregular dates and payments (positive and negative) and calculates the rate of return represented by the payments...